# Why when I add a new file to the archive, using ZipArchive, the date of change varies?

Tags: c#

There are something problem,when I am using `ZipArchive`.

The directory's files modify date always update.

[image: screenshot. date modify is changes]

Code example

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) + "_patch" + Path.GetExtension(path), FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true, Encoding.GetEncoding(866)))
    {
        foreach (var file in listInsertFiles)
        {
            var bytes = file.Data;
            var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry($@"{file.Path}/{file.Name}.{file.Ext}", CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
                zipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

    }
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Because you create new ZIP every time rather than adding a file to existing one?

Comment: But I add existing files to the zip

Comment: If you mean *"When I modify a file the date of change is updated"*, that's by design, because you *change* it. If that's not what you mean, please clarify.

Comment: You create a new .zip file, thus why it is *modified* and the date of *change* section is changed. Maybe you want to look at the date of **creation** ?

Comment: I want add exists file to zip archive without modify date edit. How can i do this?

Comment: @MiXaiL from the code provided it is definitely _not_ adding files to the existing ZIP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.lastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx :

> When you create a new entry programmatically by calling the
>   CreateEntry method, the LastWriteTime property for the entry is
>   automatically set to the time of execution.

You need to explicitly set the value of `zipArchiveEntry.LastWriteTime`.